# Anyone know application to archive GoPro, MP4 and MOV movie material

Tags: avi, mov, gopro

I have a lot of movie material, because i have a GoPro camera. This is in the MOV format.

I want an application that can spot the material and archive what is in it and based on this log make searches and export to e.g. Avid, Final Cut Pro and even Windows Movie Maker.

Is there such an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used OlympicLog (http://www.olympiclog.net). This application allows you to quickly shuttle through the material and make annotations about it.
After this is done, you can fuzzy search these annotations and make a selection. This selection can be exported to an EDL, a Windows Movie Maker project file. It workes quite nice!

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try this!